# Autoload source code updates for flask on page refresh

Tags: python, nginx, fabric, supervisord

I am looking to see visual updates to my page, after updating them on a `flask` server running via `fabric`, `supervisor`, `nginx`.

For example, if I modify a `.css` file, or `index.html`, and reload the page I do not see any updates such as changing the background from `blue` to `green`, or `new text` added to `index.html`

What do I have to set to see these types of changes?

Thank you.

Comment: you have to restart web server or you have to clear cache in web browser.

Comment: Really? This requires a reboot of the server to do?

Comment: well, if you change only css, html, js and you don't use any caching system in web server then you don't have to restart server. You should see changes after refreshing page. But sometimes web browser may cache pages and you have to clear this cache.

Comment: @Jshee:  when @furas talks about restarting the web server, he means flask/gunicorn (e.g., `systemctl restart gunicorn` or `service gunicorn restart`).  Are you using anything to compile/aggregate your assets like webpack?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Flask to serve your static assets (this is often the case for development environments)? If so, you might want to look into the SEND_FILE_MAX_AGE_DEFAULT setting, which has a default of 12 hours - this means that Flask will cache your static assets for 12 hours, and that might explain why you are not seeing updates to your CSS/JS.

See the docs on [Configuration Handling](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/config/) for more info. Typically for development, you will want to set this value to 0.